# Any pitfalls with this regex that matches ampersands not already encoded

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I want to encode ampersands that have not already been encoded. I came up with this regex

```
/&(?=[^a])/
```

It seems to work good so far, but seeing as how I'm not much of a regex expert, I am asking if any potential pitfalls can be seen in this regex?

Essentially it needs to convert `&` to `&amp;` but leave the `&` in `&amp;` as is (so as not to get `&amp;amp;`)

Thanks

### Update

Thanks for the answers. It seems I wasn't *thinking* broadly enough to cover all bases. This seems like a common pitfall of regexs themselves (having to think of all possibilities which may make your regex get false positives). It sure does beat my original one `str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $string);`  :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even better would be [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html#item__pattern_) to verify & isn't followed by amp;

```
/&(?!amp;)/
```

Though that will change any ampersands used for *other* entities. If you're likely to have others, then how about something like

```
/&(?!#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)/
```

This will look for an ampersand, but asserting that it is NOT followed by an optional hash symbol (for numeric entities), a series of alphanumerics and a semicolon, which should cover [named and numeric entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) like `&quote;` or `&#170;`

### Test code

```
$text="It&rsquo;s 30 &#176; outside & very hot. T-shirt &amp; shorts needed!";

$text=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $text);

echo "$text\n";
```

Which will output

```
It&rsquo;s 30 &#176; outside &amp; very hot. T-shirt &amp; shorts needed!
```

which is more easily read as *"It’s 30 ° outside & very hot. T-shirt & shorts needed!"*

### Alternative for PHP 5.2.3+

As Ionut G. Stan points out below, from PHP 5.2.3 you can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) with a fourth parameter of *false* to prevent double-encoding, e.g.

```
$text=htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8",false);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will apply it for any other encoded char.

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP version is >= 5.2.3 you could use the fourth parameter of the [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function. When set to false it will not convert existing entities.

Comment: Thank you, but at the moment I just want to encode ampersands. But your link is very useful! +1

Comment: +1 yes, I didn't know about that either, will mention in my answer

Answer (score 1):

In Perl that would be:

```
$content =~ s/&(?!\w+;)/&amp;/g;
```

It uses a negative lookahead of 1 or more word chars, meaning "an ampersand that is not followed by one or more word chars and immediately followed  a semicolon. Though the use os the shortcut \w is not as safe as a specific char range for this particular case. A better option would be:

```
$content =~ s/&(?![a-z]+;)/&amp;/g;
```

And just case you have some uppercase animal in your data:

```
$content =~ s/&(?![a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you have other entities in your document? What happens with if you're talking about a q&a session?

I'd isolate the ampersand rather than guess at context, and then use backreferences in your replacement string

```
/(\W)&(\W)/$1&amp;$2/
```

Answer (score 0):

That would fail in a case where the character 'a' follows an ampersand but wasn't "amp;" like &and &also &apple...

&(?!amp;)