# Why won't this ampersand matching regexp work?

Tags: php, regex, drupal

I need to use this PHP [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636781/any-pitfalls-with-this-regex-that-matches-ampersands-not-already-encoded/636793#636793) to convert `&` to ampersand. I am using the exact same test code as Paul Dixon has written it, but no ampersands are replaced in my code. Why? I am using PHP 5.2.6.

```
$str_fix = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $str);
```

The following, simpler but incorrect (it will also replace the `&` in `&amp;`) regexp works:

```
$str_fix = preg_replace('/&/', '&amp;', $str);
```

EDIT: Damnit, the issue isn't regexp/PHP related but Drupal! Yes, I am using this snippet in a Drupal module and for some reason Drupal converts `&amp;` to `&`.

Comment: Post an example of a `$str` on which it fails, seems to work fine to me

Comment: I'll say it: Works perfectly fine for me. And I can't see any regex problem either. Is it possible you checked `$str` instead of `$str_fix`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

If Drupal is replacing `&amp;` with `&` you can just double escape the entity:

```
$str_fix = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;amp;', $str);
```

Then Drupal will output `&amp;` which was your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

What about using str_replace('&', '&amp ;', $str)?

Comment: That isn't enough as it will replace & in any existing &amp;

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us an example input string?

```
echo preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', "Dogs & Cats &amp; budgies\n");
```

correctly produces

```
Dogs &amp; Cats &amp; budgies
```